# VBA code to convert all formulas in a spreadsheet to values except last active row

Tags: vba, excel

Since I input a new row of data every week in my workbook, I need Excel to recognize what the last active row is, and everything above that needs to be changed from formulas to values. This is because I don't want my previous weeks data to change to the most recent data when the reference sheet is updated each week. I Use a macro that will Copy/Insert a new row with the same formula as the row above it, so the last row of data contains all of the formulas which is why i don't want that changed. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!
Here is what I have for my copy/insert formula below last active row:

```
Sub RunAll()

 Dim ws As Worksheet
 For Each ws In Sheets
    ws.Activate

    ' Go to last cell
    Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select

    ' Copy formula from cell above
    Rows(Selection.Row - 1).Copy
    Rows(Selection.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown
Next ws
```

End Sub

Comment: Create a range that includes all the rows to the second to last.  Lets call it `rng` then you would use `rng.Value = .rng.Value`

Comment: If you post your existing code someone may suggest an addition which would do what you want.  Much harder to start with nothing.

Comment: Sorry i don' t know how to set it up good. This is my copy/Insert new row copying the formulas from the row above, now i just need to add a step that will change the row that it copied the formula from back to a value instead of formula

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we used column **A** and that the last value in column **A** marks the last row entered.  This will remove formulas from all but the bottom row:

```
Sub FormulaKiller()
    Dim N As Long, rng As Range

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(N - 1, Columns.Count))

    rng.Copy
    rng.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

As *Scott Craner* points out, we can replace:

```
rng.Copy
rng.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

with:

```
rng.value=rng.value
```

This avoids using the clipboard and also does not disturb the Selection state of the worksheet.

Comment: @ScottCraner  Updated as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
With Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0)
    .Copy
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With
```